# how to append the text in the first column to all columns linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a large tab delimited file which looks like:

```
rhaB:   IENJKMAH_01395  MACAJNEK_00455  OLCKBDOH_04002  PMOGBMCF_03363  ANGDFNGL_03589
exuT_1: OLCKBDOH_00247  EHNKCCHC_00463  MACAJNEK_00987  PMOGBMCF_00492  LPCGNNBB_01394
recA:   OLCKBDOH_01231  MOEFEGAP_03152  JFGDENGL_01411  DNGGHEME_03701  KFALDAGO_00482
lldP:   OLCKBDOH_02876  EHNKCCHC_01431  HHOCJGFI_02180  MACAJNEK_01950  KDLNNIOI_00263
```

I want to add the text from the first column to the end of the contents in each column, so that the output looks like

```
rhaB:   IENJKMAH_01395_rhaB MACAJNEK_00455_rhaB OLCKBDOH_04002_rhaB PMOGBMCF_03363_rhaB ANGDFNGL_03589_rhaB
```

The reason for this is I have to ultimately delete the first column and I want to be able to backtrack these ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk '{suffix=substr($1,1,length($1)-1); for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i"_"suffix}1' file
```

The output:

```
rhaB: IENJKMAH_01395_rhaB MACAJNEK_00455_rhaB OLCKBDOH_04002_rhaB PMOGBMCF_03363_rhaB ANGDFNGL_03589_rhaB
exuT_1: OLCKBDOH_00247_exuT_1 EHNKCCHC_00463_exuT_1 MACAJNEK_00987_exuT_1 PMOGBMCF_00492_exuT_1 LPCGNNBB_01394_exuT_1
recA: OLCKBDOH_01231_recA MOEFEGAP_03152_recA JFGDENGL_01411_recA DNGGHEME_03701_recA KFALDAGO_00482_recA
lldP: OLCKBDOH_02876_lldP EHNKCCHC_01431_lldP HHOCJGFI_02180_lldP MACAJNEK_01950_lldP KDLNNIOI_00263_lldP
```

---

`suffix=substr($1,1,length($1)-1)` - get the **1**st column value without trailing `:`

`for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i"_"suffix` - adding suffix value to each next column

---

To get a "*beautified*" column output you may pipe with `column -tx`:

```
awk '{suffix=substr($1,1,length($1)-1); for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i"_"suffix}1' file | column -tx
```

The output:

```
rhaB:    IENJKMAH_01395_rhaB    MACAJNEK_00455_rhaB    OLCKBDOH_04002_rhaB    PMOGBMCF_03363_rhaB    ANGDFNGL_03589_rhaB
exuT_1:  OLCKBDOH_00247_exuT_1  EHNKCCHC_00463_exuT_1  MACAJNEK_00987_exuT_1  PMOGBMCF_00492_exuT_1  LPCGNNBB_01394_exuT_1
recA:    OLCKBDOH_01231_recA    MOEFEGAP_03152_recA    JFGDENGL_01411_recA    DNGGHEME_03701_recA    KFALDAGO_00482_recA
lldP:    OLCKBDOH_02876_lldP    EHNKCCHC_01431_lldP    HHOCJGFI_02180_lldP    MACAJNEK_01950_lldP    KDLNNIOI_00263_lldP
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the detail too.